# How is this page being injected?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, code-injection

I'm trying to find the rest of our pages that a hacker/bot is getting into our system from, but in order to do that I need to understand the one page we do know they got through and how that happened to I can look for the same issue repeating in other pages.

I'm studying up on this stuff, but it's a battle.  I was sort of desperately hoping someone could explain it to me and how I could fix it so I can hunt and apply it to more pages.

```html
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Xsl" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Xml.Xpath" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Configuration" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<script language="VB" runat="server" EnableSessionState=true>

Sub Page_Load(Src As Object, E As EventArgs) 
 
   Dim assess as Integer
   if Request.QueryString("assess")<>"" then
      assess = Request.QueryString("assess")
   else
      assess=1
   end if
   
  Dim HTMLxsl as XslTransform = New XslTransform()
  Dim xmlDoc as XMLDocument = New XMLDocument()
  Dim HTML as String    
  
  ' *** load xsl ***
  HTMLxsl.Load(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("webfileroot") & "\xsl\assesshtml.xsl")
  ' *** load xml ***
  xmlDoc.Load(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("webfileroot") & "\xsl\assessments.xml")
  'Create an XsltArgumentList.
  Dim xslArg As XsltArgumentList = New XsltArgumentList
  xslArg.AddParam("assess_id", "", assess)

  Dim writer as StringWriter = new StringWriter()
  HTMLxsl.Transform(xmldoc, xslArg, writer, nothing)
  HTML = writer.ToString()

  Response.Write(HTML)

End Sub  

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you accept an id from the querystring with the code. Request.QueryString("assess"). Make sure you do some validation before using that value later otherwise the attacker can use that parameter to do XSLT Injection.

Comment: See @AndreaAngella comment, the hacker might be passing in escaped html into the `assess` query parameter.